# How can I add a href to an entire figure

Tags: html, css

I have the following html snippet:

```
 <figure>
        <img src='image.png' height="250" width="250">
        <figcaption>Album name goes here
            <br>Year goes here
        </figcaption>
</figure>
```

And the following css:

```
figure {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px;
    margin: 20px; /* adjust as needed */
}
figure img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
figure figcaption {
    border: 1px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

It would end up looking like this:

[image]

How can I set it up so that if a user clicks on the image or the caption under it they get directed to a new page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<a target="_blank" href="link_here">`your image code`</a>` Also you need to use `target="_blank"` to open new browser window.

```
<figure>
  <a target="_blank" href="your_link_here">
    <img src='image.png' height="250" width="250">
    ...
    ...
  </a>
</figure>
```

Comment: Where is the `<figure>` element?

Answer (score 2):

You can just put it inside an anchor tag like:

```
<figure>
    <a href="https://www.google.com">
    <img src='image.png' height="250" width="250">
        <figcaption>Album name goes here
            <br>Year goes here
        </figcaption>
    </a>
</figure>
```